# Update pagination after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a pagination script that is working fine under normal events. ie with no ajax calls etc. What I am doing is performing a search and when the results are displayed, the pagination is not getting updated. What I need to happen is when the search is finished and the results displaye, is to update the numer of pages to reflect the results of the search. For example if there is 1 result only show 1 page. if there are 10 results then update the number of paes based on the results.

I would be grateful if someone could help with this. Many thanks

js code

```
$(function() {
  $('table.paginated').each(function() {
    var currentPage = 0;
    var numPerPage = 8;
    var $table = $(this);
    var numRows = $table.find('tbody tr').length;
    var numPages = Math.ceil(numRows / numPerPage);
    var $pager1 = $('<div class="pager"></div>');
    var $pager2 = "";
    var $numberPicker = $('<div class="numberPicker"></div>');
    var dropdown = $('<select class="options"></select>');
    var dropdown2 = "";
    $table.bind('repaginate', function() {
      $table.find('tbody tr').hide().slice(currentPage * numPerPage, (currentPage + 1) * numPerPage).show();
    });
    $table.trigger('repaginate');

    function rePage(numPages) {
      $('.page-number').remove();
      for (var page = 0; page < numPages; page++) {
        $('<span class="page-number"></span>').text(page + 1).bind('click', {
          newPage: page
        }, function(event) {
          var selected = $(this).index();
          var selected2 = ($(this).index()) + numPages;
          currentPage = event.data['newPage'];
          $table.trigger('repaginate');
          $('span.page-number').removeClass('active');
          $("span.page-number").each(function(index) {
            if (index === selected) {
              $(this).addClass('active');
              $("span.page-number:eq(" + selected2 + ")").addClass('active')
            }
          });
        }).appendTo($pager1).addClass('clickable');
      }
      $pager2 = $pager1.clone(true);
      $pager2.insertAfter($table);
    }
    rePage(numPages);
    $pager1.insertBefore($table);
    $pager2.insertAfter($table);
    $('span.page-number:first-child').addClass('active');
    $([5, numPerPage, 10, 20]).each(function() {
      var $num = this;
      $('<option></option>').text(this).attr('value', this).appendTo(dropdown);
    });
    dropdown.bind('change', function() {
      var oldNumPerPage = numPerPage;
      numPerPage = this.value;
      numPages = Math.ceil(numRows / numPerPage);
      $table.trigger('repaginate');
      rePage(numPages);
      currentPage = Math.ceil((currentPage * oldNumPerPage) / numPerPage);
      $("span.page-number:eq(" + currentPage + ")").trigger('click');
      $('.options').val(numPerPage);
      $('.options2').val(numPerPage);
    }).insertBefore($pager2);
    dropdown2 = dropdown.clone(true);
    dropdown2.addClass('options2');
    dropdown2.insertAfter($pager1);
    $('.options').val(numPerPage);
    $('.options2').val(numPerPage);
  });
});
```

Button search js

```
$(function() {
  $('#btn-search').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var search = $("#search").val();
    $.ajax({
      url: "tabletestajax.php",
      method: 'POST',
      data: {
        search1: search
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $("#search").val('');
        $(".paginated tbody").empty();
        var result = $.trim(data);
        if (result === "enter a search term") {
          $("input[name='search']").val(result).css({
            'color': 'red'
          });
          return false;
        } else if (result === "No Results Found") {
          $(".paginated tbody").html('<div>' + result + '</div>');
          return false;
        } else {
          $(".paginated tbody").html(result);
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: In your search functions `success` part, just call the pagination function with the new data. There are many pagination tutorials out there, it's not difficult to get your version up and running by googling

Comment: @ChrisSatchell I have googled till i'm blue in the face. Cannot seem to find any examples or tutorials to get me started. Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, but that is bs. There are lots of libraries that do it for you and enough tutorials if you want to do it yourself. You already understand the core concept, all you need to do is move your pagination code to it's own function and call it with either a) the table data or b) the data from the ajax backend. The code pretty much stays the same, the key difference is adapting both `var numRows = $table.find('tbody tr').length;` and `var numRows = data.length;`

Comment: @ChrisSatchell I do not want to use a library but would rather learn by doing it myself. Most of the search material I found was for plugins. Thanks anyway. Cheers